# How to determine if two records are 1 year apart (using a timestamp)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I need to analyze some weblogs and determine if a user has visited once, taken a year break, and visited again. I want to add a flag to every row (Y/N) with a VisitId that meets the above criteria.

How would I go about creating this sql?

Here are the fields I have, that I think need to be used (by analyzing the timestamp of the first page of each visit):

- VisitID - each visit has a unique Id (ie. 12356, 12345, 16459)
- UserID - each user has one Id (ie. steve = 1, ted = 2, mark = 12345, etc...)
- TimeStamp -  looks like this: 2010-01-01 00:32:30.000

`select VisitID, UserID, TimeStamp from page_view_t where pageNum = 1;`

thanks - any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean a year *or more*, or *exactly one year*?

Comment: SQL Server is the DBMS... not sure if it is relational or not

Comment: @tylercomp - it is.  Version is also important.  What version of SS is it?

Comment: @JNK SQL Server 2005 version 9.0.4053

Comment: @ Adam Robinson - A year or more, if they took a 2 year break I would also want that return flagged

Comment: Do you only want to know if there was a break of 1+ years between the last two years or if there was a break of 1+ years between any two consecutive visits?  

For example would this count as meeting the criteria? A user visited the two times in 2009, then didn't visit the site for more than year, but then now has been visiting 1 time per month since that break.

Comment: @AdamPorad In your example I would want to flag the user on his first visit in 2009 and on his first return in over a year.  Any subsequent visits that don't have a year in between wouldn't matter.  I am basically trying to reclassify a new visitor by adding a 1 year delta.

Comment: @tylercomp: Do you mean that the very first visit should be flagged as well?

Comment: @AndriyM Yes, but that isn't really the hard part, I am struggling to figure out how to compare the two dates when the userId is the same but visitId is so different (i.e. 21345, 12542).  I don't know how to create a query complex enough to compare the two...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could rank every user's rows, then join the ranked row set to itself to compare adjacent rows:

```
;
WITH ranked AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    rnk = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserID ORDER BY TimeStamp)
  FROM page_view_t
),
flagged AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    IsReturnVisit = CASE
      WHEN EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM ranked
        WHERE UserID = r.UserID
          AND rnk = r.rnk - 1
          AND TimeStamp <= DATEADD(YEAR, -1, r.TimeStamp)
      )
      THEN 'Y'
      ELSE 'N'
    END
  FROM ranked r
)
SELECT
  VisitID,
  UserID,
  TimeStamp,
  IsReturnVisit
FROM flagged
```

Note: the above flags only return visits.

**UPDATE**

To flag the first visits same as return visits, the `flagged` CTE could be modified as follows:

```
…
SELECT
  *,
  IsFirstOrReturnVisit = CASE
    WHEN p.UserID IS NULL OR r.TimeStamp >= DATEADD(YEAR, 1, p.TimeStamp)
    THEN 'Y'
    ELSE 'N'
  END
FROM ranked r
  LEFT JOIN ranked p ON r.UserID = p.UserID AND r.rnk = p.rnk + 1
…
```

---

References that might be useful:

- [WITH common_table_expression (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx)
- [Ranking Functions (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx)
- [ROW_NUMBER (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Andriy! I am testing it right now but this looks like what I needed to know, I didn't know about ROW_NUMBER()!

Comment: @tylercomp: Thanks. Yes, ranking functions enable you to write simple and (though not always) efficient queries. I was really fascinated when I first became aware of them.

Answer (score 1):

The other guy was faster but since I took time to do it and it's a completely different approach I might as well post It :D.

```
SELECT pv2.VisitID,
       pv2.UserID,  
       pv2.TimeStamp, 
       CASE WHEN pv1.VisitID IS NOT NULL 
             AND pv3.VisitID IS NULL
       THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS IsReturnVisit
FROM page_view_t pv2
LEFT JOIN page_view_t pv1 ON pv1.UserID = pv2.UserID
                          AND pv1.VisitID <> pv2.VisitID
                          AND (pv1.TimeStamp <= DATEADD(YEAR, -1, pv2.TimeStamp)
                               OR pv2.TimeStamp <= DATEADD(YEAR, -1, pv1.TimeStamp))
                          AND pv1.pageNum = 1
LEFT JOIN page_view_t pv3 ON pv1.UserID = pv3.UserID
                          AND (pv3.TimeStamp BETWEEN pv1.TimeStamp AND pv2.TimeStamp
                               OR pv3.TimeStamp BETWEEN pv2.TimeStamp AND pv1.TimeStamp)
                          AND pv3.pageNum = 1
WHERE pv2.pageNum = 1
```

Comment: No big deal Thanks for the + 1 anyway

Answer (score 1):

Assuming page_view_t table stores UserID and TimeStamp details of each visit of the user, the following query will return users who have visited taking a break of at least an year (365 days) between two consecutive visits.

```
select t1.UserID
from page_view_t t1
where (
    select datediff(day, max(t2.[TimeStamp]), t1.[TimeStamp])
    from page_view_t t2
    where t2.UserID = t1.UserID and t2.[TimeStamp] < t1.[TimeStamp]
    group by t2.UserID
) >= 365
```